# javascript getting drop down box value

Tags: javascript, dropdownbox

I want to get the selected value from a dropdown box.
Then I want to use that value to change the background-image.

The two code snippits I think are useful:

```
document.observe("dom:loaded",function(){
initialize();

addTextboxes();
var sel = document.getElementById("select");
for(i = 0; i < pieces.length; i++) {
    pieces[i].observe("click",function(event){
        moveThis(event.toElement.innerHTML-1);
    });
    pieces[i].style.backgroundImage = sel.value;        
}

var e = document.getElementById("select");
alert(e.options[e.selectedIndex].value);

var value = document.getElementById("select").value;
alert(value);

});

function addTextboxes(){
var sel = document.createElement("select");
//Add the options  
sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text0","url(luigi1.jpg)");  
sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text1","url(luigi2.jpg)");  
sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text2","url(luigi3.jpg)");  
sel.options[sel.options.length] = new Option("text3","url(luigi4.jpg)");  
//add the element to the form  
document.getElementById("overall").appendChild(sel);    
}
```

I have already put two alerts in it to test if something happens, but they don't even show up.
Also, when I place the forloop in the addTextboxes() function, then it changes the background to the first selected option, but doesn't change when you change the box.

Comment: Have you tried putting an alert inside the click handler to see what element is being returned?

Answer (score 0):

I see a few things that need to be changed in your code.

- You can't use `getElementById("select")` without giving an element the select id. Ids are different from tag types, and must be unique throughout your whole page. In the fiddle below, I'm using 'mySelect' for this, to avoid confusion.
- You shouldn't listen for a `click` event on each option. Instead, you should listen for the `change` event on the entire select element. After a change, the `value` of the select element will be the value of the option that was chosen.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9y22x/1/) with these changes

After making those changes, the value of chosen option is now displayed in an alert box.
From here, you'd be able to change the background image, or do anything else.

Comment: The click event is for something else, but this was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a bunch. The fiddle is very helpful.

Answer (score -1):

With the use of jQuery its simply this line here

```
$( "#selectbox option:selected" ).text();
```

That will get the text of the selected option, you could always get the value using this method:

```
$( "#selectbox option:selected" ).val();
```

Comment: The OP isn't using jQuery and it's a bit much to expect the inclusion of the whole library for just this.